# How to split a list of data.frame and apply a function to one column?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a small question about apply functions.
For example I have:

```
l <- list(a = data.frame(A1=rep(10,5),B1=c(1,1,1,2,2),C1=c(5,10,20,7,30)),
          b = data.frame(A1=rep(20,5),B1=c(3,3,4,4,4),C1=c(3,5,10,20,30)))
```

I want to find a minimum C1 for each B1. The result should be

```
$a
  A1 B1 C1
  10  1  5
  10  2  7

$b
  A1 B1 C1
  20  3  3
  20  4  10
```

I know how to do it with 'for', but it have to be a easier way with 'lapply', but I couldn't make it works.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach that matches your desired output:

```
lapply(l, function(x) {
  temp <- ave(x[["C1"]], x["B1"], FUN = min)
  x[x[["C1"]] == temp, ]
})
# $a
#   A1 B1 C1
# 1 10  1  5
# 4 10  2  7
# 
# $b
#   A1 B1 C1
# 1 20  3  3
# 3 20  4 10
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, many thanks. I didn't know this kind of ave utilisation

Answer (score 4):

What about combining `lapply` and `tapply`:

```
lapply(l, function(i) tapply(i$C1, i$B1, min))
$a
1 2 
5 7 

$b
3  4 
3 10
```

---

The trick to thinking about multiple operations is to split the task into bits. SO,

1. Minimum `C1` for each `B1`. How do we do this for a **single** data frame?

   ```
   i = l[[1]]
   tapply(i$C1, i$B1, min)
   ```
2. Each element of a list? Just use `lapply`:

   ```
   lapply(l, function(i) tapply(i$C1, i$B1, min))
   ```

If you can't do step 1, you won't be able to manage step 2.

Answer (score 3):

Having recently succumbed to the siren song of the `data.table` package and its combination of versatility and speed for doing operations like this, I submit yet another solution:

```
library(data.table)
lapply(l, function(dat) {
    data.table(dat, key="B1,C1")[list(unique(B1)), mult="first"]
})
```

If retaining the original column order is important, for some reason, the `data.table()` call could be wrapped by `setcolorder(..., names(dat))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try llply + dcast from the plyr/reshape2 toolbox:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

    l <- list(a = data.frame(A1=rep(10,5),B1=c(1,1,1,2,2),C1=c(5,10,20,7,30)),
              b = data.frame(A1=rep(20,5),B1=c(3,3,4,4,4),C1=c(3,5,10,20,30)))

    llply(l, function (x) {dcast (x, A1+B1~., value.var="C1", min)})
```